# Replace the specific value between & in string

Tags: jquery

Example:

I have string like this : `http://example.com/path/?value1=123&value2=334&value3=x2y&value4=2bx`

How can I exactly replace string above with exact value I want.

Such as, I want to replace to change `value2=334` to `value2=b2y`

```
I mean that the current value of value2 will be replaced with b2y.
```

I use Jquery only. Thank for your support.

Comment: @NisargShah: Have you read carefully the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- for getting query param from any url

```
function getQueryVariable(url, variable) {
     var query = url.substring(1);
     var vars = query.split('&');
     for (var i=0; i<vars.length; i++) {
          var pair = vars[i].split('=');
          if (pair[0] == variable) {
            return pair[1];
          }
     }

     return false;
  }
```

**Example**
var url = 'http://www.example.com/hello.png?w=100&h=101&bg=white';

```
 var w = getQueryVariable(url, 'w');//100
  var h = getQueryVariable(url, 'h');//101
  var bg = getQueryVariable(url, 'bg');//white
```

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9622263/8621306

2- Set the Query Param of a url

```
function updateQueryStringParameter(uri, key, value) {
  var re = new RegExp("([?&])" + key + "=.*?(&|$)", "i");
  var separator = uri.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? "&" : "?";
  if (uri.match(re)) {
    return uri.replace(re, '$1' + key + "=" + value + '$2');
  }
  else {
    return uri + separator + key + "=" + value;
  }
}
```

**Credit**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6021027/8621306